# Loop through each object property for amcharts stacked column charts

Tags: javascript, jquery, amcharts

Hi I am using ajax to get php mysql data and display it to amcharts stacked column charts but since I am working on a stacked column charts I need to define each title and value field individually to produced each series of a chart.

Here is my jsfiddle :
http://jsfiddle.net/o7cm6nkh/

Is there a way  I could loop through each property name ? to produce an output like this and not by manually inserting them?

```
{
    "numberFormatter": {
            "precision": 2,
            "decimalSeparator": ".",
            "thousandsSeparator": ","
        },
    "fillAlphas": 0.8,
    "labelText": "[[title]]<br>" + "[[value]]",



    "labelPosition": "middle",
    "lineAlpha": 0.3,
    "title": "MAN",
    "type": "column",
    "color": "#000000",
    "valueField": "MAN"
  }, {
    "numberFormatter": {
            "precision": 2,
            "decimalSeparator": ".",
            "thousandsSeparator": ","
        },
    "fillAlphas": 0.8,
    "labelText":"[[title]]<br>" + "[[value]]",


    "labelPosition": "middle",
    "lineAlpha": 0.3,
    "title": "PAN",
    "type": "column",
    "color": "#000000",
    "valueField": "PAN"
  },
  {
    "numberFormatter": {
            "precision": 2,
            "decimalSeparator": ".",
            "thousandsSeparator": ","
        },
    "fillAlphas": 0.8,
    "labelText":"[[title]]<br>" + "[[value]]",


    "labelPosition": "middle",
    "lineAlpha": 0.3,
    "title": "DAV",
    "type": "column",
    "color": "#000000",
    "valueField": "DAV"
  }
```

Comment: Could you explain the difference between the object you posted here and the object hard-coded in your JSFiddle? What do you want to transform into what?

Comment: sorry for the confusion . I want to loop to each property name to produce the output  under the graphs . because currently I am doing it manually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a template that has all the desired graph setup properties that don't change and then dynamically create your graphs array using the other properties in your data and set the other fields up as you go. Since you're more than likely going to know what your categoryField is going to be upfront, you can simply loop through the rest of the properties in your response's first array element and set your title and valueField since those are the only values that are changing.

Assuming your categoryField is always `name`:

```
  var graphs = Object.keys(response[0]).reduce(function(graphsArray, key) {
    if (key !== "name") {
      graphsArray.push({
        "fillAlphas": 0.8,
        "labelText": "[[title]]<br>" + "[[value]]",
        "labelPosition": "middle",
        "lineAlpha": 0.3,
        "title": key,
        "type": "column",
        "color": "#000000",
        //"showAllValueLabels": true,
        "valueField": key
      });
    }
    return graphsArray;
  }, []);


  // ...
  var AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
    // ...
    "graphs": graphs,
    // ...
  });
```

(Note that `numberFormatter` is not a graph-level property but a top-level chart object property)

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/o7cm6nkh/2/